# How to translate tensorflow python API to golang API

Tags: tensorflow

I want translate below tensorflow python API to golang API

```
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
```

Does any one know that, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
output, err := session.Run(
    map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
        graph.Operation("DecodeJpeg/contents").Output(0): tensor,
    }, []tf.Output{
        graph.Operation("final_result").Output(0),
    },
    nil)
```